# Django queryset of related records, but only the max from the related table

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Lets say I have two django models which are related. Groups, and People, who belong to a single group.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class Person(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='group')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    birthdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

What I would like to do, is return a queryset of the Person objects, which is composed of only those people with the greatest birthdate for each group. So if there are 5 'Groups' I want a queryset of 5 'Person' objects, determined by maxmium birthdate.

Answer (score 0):

Pls Try:

```
gruop_id = Group.objects.get(name='?').id
Person.objects.filter(group__id=gruop_id).order_by('birthdate').values()[:5]
```

I may not have understood you. Maybe, You want the reverse.

```
Person.objects.filter(group__id=gruop_id).order_by('birthdate').values().reverse()[:5]
```